# PHP Extension persistent_list?

Tags: php, php-extension

I am trying to understand persistence. I see some if statement

```
if(zend_hash_find(&EG(persistent_list), key, key_len+1, (void **)&rle)==FAILURE)
```

I am trying to replicate this code as if it were PHP. I did some research on persistent variables in PHP. All I could find was things that used things like $_*SESSION. However, I don't have too much experience in PHP. So, I am uncertain to what functions create persistent connections. However, I am assuming $*_SESSION, $_*POST, and $*_GET, all create persistent connections. Assuming that persistent connections is tied to this list.

Would I have to loop through $__SESSION keys to make this equivalent to the code above? Am I understanding this right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer, again lol.

There is a function in php called apd_dump_persistent_resources.
This will mimic that if statement